# Add additional file to global path in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I am new to NodeJS/ JavaScript and I want to add an additional File to my Global variable Declaration. My Idear:

I want do add a Language File to my Global Path

```
var getLanguage = require('./language.js');
module.exports = {
retryAssertionTimeout: 2000,
url:'https://10.99.8.81',
language: getLanguage.de_de,
```

In Language File I have Two Definitions, one for german and one for english.

So if I change

```
language: getLanguage.de_de,
```

to

```
language: getLanguage.en_en,
```

i want to change the used langugage.

the declaration in my language file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
de_de: {
    verzeichnisse: "Verzeichnisse",
    benachrichtigungen: "Benachrichtigungen",
    berichte: "Berichte",
    ftp_server: "FTP Server",
  }
};
```

in my functions i call it with

```
 var data = client.globals;
 var language = data.language;
 .goto(language.benutzer) //Benutzer is declared in my full file.
```

but this just not work.

Any idears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[laguage.js]
var chinese = {
    game : "游戏"
}

var english = {
    game : "game"
}

function getLanguage(type) {
    if (type == 1) {
        return chinese;
    } else if (type == 2) {
        return english;
    }
}

exports.getLanguage = getLanguage;

[main.js]
var getLanguage = require('./language.js');
var language = getLanguage.getLanguage(1);
console.log(language);

[result]
{ game: '游戏'}
```